# Blender python scripting

Tags: python, camera, blender

I want to use `blender` to programmatically move the camera around the scene while remaining focused on a particular location. What's the easiest way to make the camera look at an object without having to specify `rx`,`ry`,and `rz`. I'm looking for the Python function to call and not do it through the `blender` GUI. I am using `blender 2.65`.

Comment: I'd try to use the origin / center of rotation point as the marker for the point to look at, then programmatically access its coordinates. Or how else would you like to specify the object?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make the camera look at an object is the `Edit Object` **Actuator**. There you can replace `Add Object` to `Track To` and then you just need to specify an object.

Perhaps you can change it in the game with a **python script**, using `EditObjectActuator.track_object`